# Project stages collapsed while reloading or re running server in ODOO

Tags: odoo

The ordering of the project stages changes automatically.

```
<header>
   <field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" clickable="True"
          options="{'fold_field': 'fold'}"/>
</header>`
```

Should I have to put  tag over field name to avoid such things